# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5551).

Comment: I asked this last year as well and it was unanswered (I believe). How often are the community promotion adds gonna be shown when they pass the threshold? The most important consideration behind of the question is the question 'Do the promotion adds each gonna get a number of views that is fixed per add, or are they gonna share some total amounts of views (which means that they get fewer views per add if more adds pass the threshold)?  (yeah, I tend to think of these things)

Comment: It's not a question with a straight answer, @Martijn: it's different for registered and anonymous users, for instance. It also depends on the number of answers a question has. And then, if the site shows ads for SO jobs, it further complicates things... But I'll try to see if anyone has a bit more detail that could be explained succinctly :)

Comment: It doesn't need to be a detailed answer, but just sufficient to be able to help with the particular issue that I mentioned "should I vote strategically on the few that I like best versus should I vote for anything that I like". If you like then you can simplify my question to "If a certain add passes the threshold, does this decrease the rate at which other community promotion adds are shown?" which should be able to be answered with a simple yes/no answer.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings All of the "leftover" inventory goes to various ads, with varying priorities.  Community ads fall into this bucket, at a lower priority than paid ads.  So the more community ads we have, the less they will serve because they are all sharing those leftover impressions.  But the number of those impressions isn't fixed... it changes base on our amount of "leftover" inventory.  So it can also vary month to month based on how much we sell.

Comment: It would really help if the community came up with some sort of guidance on what kind of ad they want to see. Last year I brought two community ads promoting R and mlr (a mainstream machine learning package written in R) and both were downvoted by the community.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you mean, @Firebug, the voting feature is _exactly_ meant for the community to express what they want and don't want to see :)

Comment: @JNat I meant a thread where this "guidance" was exposed and voted by the community, or at least a thread were we could expose community ads drafts (because otherwise your work is going to waste if it's downvoted, better to know it beforehand that's not what CV wants)

Answer (score 12):

[image: Operations Research Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Need data? Open Data Stack Exchange]

Comment: We sometimes get people coming to CV to ask for datasets. The [opendata.SE] SE site can help them. It is still in beta, but I hope it thrives & I think we could try to support them with their logo & link as a community promotion ad here.

Comment: I have suggested this in previous years as well. I believe this is the preferred image.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting

Answer (score -8):

[image]

Comment: Is 'quantum machine learning' so different from 'machine learning' (which is already on topic here on [stats.SE], & reduplicated to some degree (& unnecessarily so, IMHO) on [datascience.SE], that we need *another* SE site for it? My gut reaction is *no*, & we should not support this.

Comment: I find it funny that there is already a quantum SE before we actually have large quantum computers that are practical to use and available to the mass. How many quantum computers are currently out there? And to make it statistic, what is the number of quantum computers as a function of the bits in the processor?