# How often/how quickly do community ads get posted?

Tags: support

I posted [an ad](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5634/244353) to the [Community Promotion Ads - 2019](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5551/244353) thread, and the ad has had the requisite 6 votes for several days, but as far as I can tell it has not yet run on the Q&A site. Just wanted to check to see how the timing works, or whether there's something else I need to do to trigger the ad to run. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, but here's an old [meta.SE] thread about how long it would take for 2016's ads to start showing up ([When will 2016's community promotion ads start being shown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274572/187282)). My take away is that it is likely to take a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5551 it seems to be already active, it just gets no clicks.

Well.... one now, since I just clicked on it. Now it says 0.07 clicks per day. So that means it was online 14 or 15 days ago (today is May 2th). That is about 1 or 2 days after you posted the add.

Beyond that, I have no idea if, how often and where those ads are shown. I have never seen them.